# How to fix the logic flow of of a recursion function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to understand the `return` and recursion, here's my code.

```
def test(n, k):
    # print n
    if n == 5:
        print k
        return

    for i in range(k, -1, -1):
        test(n+1, i) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(0,10)
```

I'm expecting the code would stop at the first time *n* reach to *5* and print *10*.

However, the code is going through all the possible `for` loop.

I guess I'm misunderstanding the usage of `return` over the recursion call.

Is there a way to get what I want using the recursion and `for` loop structure? Or I understand something totally wrong for recursion.

Looking forward to your help.

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop is not needed here.

```
def test(n, k):
    # print n
    if n == 5:
        print(k)
        return

    test(n+1, k) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(0,10)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. By any chance, I can get the code stop at the first `n=5` while keeps the `loop`?

Comment: Use loop or recursion ; Both not needed at same time